# rdlc 2005 Add a static column to a matrix

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

given the dataset -

Name, Date, Value, Value2 (the dates are at the month level - so only MMM/yy is returned.)

Is it possible to configure a Matrix in RDLC 2005 such that it displays -

```
Static  |   Dynamic Columns         |       Static
         Date,       Date,        Date,       
Name,   Value,      Value,       Value,    Sum(Value2)
```

Or is it possible to configure the Tablix so the middle 3 columns are grouped by date?

here's how the report looks so far -

```
        Jun/12  Jul/12  Aug/12          
AA-10   406     580     406         
AA-11           100.05                  
AA-12   406     435     435
```

it just needs the sum adding to the right hand column but i cant seem to add the column at the end.

I want to display a row for each Name and the max value for each of the last 3 months with a sum of value2 at the end.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by pivoting that section of the data then using a Tablix.

DataSet becomes

```
Name, Date, Value, PrevValue, PrevPrevValue, Value2.
```

the details field has grouping on Name, with

```
Max(Value), Max(PrevValue), Max(PrevPrevValue), Sum(Value2)
```

as the field defs.

the columns titles use

```
DateAdd("m",-2,Max(Date)) ,DateAdd("m",-1,Max(Date)) ,Max(Date)
```

to provide the prev month titles.